# Display different parts of JQuery Ajax response in separate DIVs

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a script that allows the user to grade an image and then dynamically adds another form to the page to grade the next.  When the image grade is entered it is entered into a database and displayed on the page above the newly created form in a list with the ID `responds`.

All of this works great but I would also be able to show a running count of how many images have been audited at the top of the page in a `DIV` with the ID `results`.

The `JQuery`

```
$("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#grade").val()!='1')
        {
            if($("#positioning_reason").val() == '' &&
                                  $("#exposure_reason").val() == '' &&
                                  $("#equipment_reason").val() == '' &&
                                  $("#patient_reason").val() == '')
                            { 
               alert("Please select why the image was not perfect");
               return false;
            }
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "response.php",
        dataType:"text",
        data: $('#test_form').serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $('#test_form')[0].reset();
            $("#test_form").get(0).scrollIntoView();
            $("#results").display $numRows in this div          
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

});
```

response.php

```
//include db configuration file
include 'includes/db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['grade'])) 
    {
    $grade = $_POST['grade'];
    $positioning = $_POST['positioning_reason'];
    $exposure = $_POST['exposure_reason'];
    $patient = $_POST['patient_reason'];
    $equipment = $_POST['equipment_reason'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $audit_id = $_POST['audit_id'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO image(auditID, imageGrade,positioning_reasonID,exposure_reasonID,patient_reasonID,equipment_reasonID,auditDate,userID) VALUES('$audit_id', $grade,'$positioning','$exposure','$patient','$equipment',NOW(),$user_id)";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    if($result)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE auditID = '$audit_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
          $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          $my_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
          $output_array = array(
              'my_id' => $my_id,
              'grade' => $grade,
              'numRows' => $numRows
          );

    }else{

        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }

}
elseif(isset($_POST["recordToDelete"]) && strlen($_POST["recordToDelete"])>0 && is_numeric($_POST["recordToDelete"]))
{   
    $idToDelete = $_POST["recordToDelete"]; 

    $sql = "DELETE FROM image WHERE imageID = $idToDelete";
    $result = $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if(!$result)
    {     
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Could not delete record!');
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error occurred, Could not process request!');
    exit();
}
echo json_encode($output_array);
```

I would like to display the value $numRows in a div called 'results' (at present it i being displayed with all of the other results for testing purposes).  I have tried getting the $numRow value from a different php page using a separate page load function further down the page but it was very slow and the result were not always correct because of timings

Comment: Change your php script to return json instead of html and process the result on the client. You could even have your existing html fragment returned as the value of one of the json properties.

Comment: I have to admit I'm very new to ajax etc and haven't looked at json as yet so wouldn't know where to start

Comment: [Always a good place to start](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+return+json+from+php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON would be a better option, as others in the comments have pointed out.

```
if($result)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE auditID = '$audit_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
          $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          $my_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
          $output_array = array(
              'my_id' => $my_id,
              'grade' => $grade,
              'numRows' => $numRows
          );
    }
//etc...
```

Then at the end of the file:

```
echo json_encode($output_array);
```

Now you do the HTML formatting in your AJAX success function:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "response.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#test_form').serialize(),
    success:function(response){
        $("#responds").empty().append('<li id="item_'+response.my_id+'" class="audit_item">'+
        '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'+response.my_id+'">'+
        '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />'+
        'Grade - '+response.grade+' - '+response.my_id+' - '+response.numRows+'</li>'+
        '</a></div>')            
        $('#test_form')[0].reset();
        $("#test_form").get(0).scrollIntoView();
        $("#results").empty().append('<b>'+response.numRows+'</b>')
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, it always helps when you can see the advice given in context with the problem.  However, when I use it I get an error 'unexpected token <'

Comment: Add `console.log(response)` below `success:function(response){`. If the expected information doesn't appear in your JS console, check your network log and see if the page loaded returns a valid JSON. You can test the JSON by copy and pasting the entire page (response.php) and then opening your JS console and pasting it directly into there and seeing if you get an Object returned

Comment: In the JS console it says syntaxError, unexpected token <

Comment: Is there anything else being `echo`ed in your response.php? `echo json_encode($output_array);` should be the only `echo` line.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You can't just paste it in the console. You have to make it equal something. So copy the entire thing, and then add `x = ` in front of it. It then should return an object.

Comment: ok, i'll try that, in the meantime I've edited my question to show the entire contents of response.php

Comment: Make sure when you have a new line inside the `append()` javascript function, that there's a plus symbol at the end. I think there's a missing or extra symbol in your JS.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting any further, I pasted the whole page into the console and I still just get a syntaxError and I don't know how to check the network log.  What I can say is that the corresponding entires aren't being made in the sql database either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35712/discussion-between-jack-cole-and-tatty27)